How can i achieve this kind of 'light' or effect?
How can I achieve some kind of 'lighting' within the model? I don't know if it's light (like point), the same texture, or another external factor.
I leave you an example image of something I would like to achieve, in this model we can see lighting inside the object. How could you achieve something like that? I would like to please ask for help in guiding me for this, since I do not know clear options to be able to do it.
Thanks in advance.

This is my setup, and a basic geometry to show what i'm trying to achieve.


(Ignore the simple geometry, it just looks like this because i'm just working on the material, not the model right now).

What about having two separate objects? The blue one is like a nut shell: empty inside, but has thickness (assign Glass shader). The red one is just an abstract geometric form inside the blue shell (assign Emission shader).

it could work, but since the object is transparent, the light is sold off the object and begins to bounce off the rest of the elements in the scene, causing the effect to be lost.
